# Why doesn't .charCodeAt() ensure that you can find the missing letter in this Javascript Algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question**

Find the missing letter in the passed letter range and return it.

If all letters are present in the range, return undefined.

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {

  let testArr = [0, str.charCodeAt(0)];

  str.split('').forEach((item, index)=>{
      testArr[0] = testArr[1];
      testArr[1] = item.charCodeAt(0);
      if(testArr[1] != (testArr[0] + 1)){
        return str[index];
      }
    })

  return undefined;
}

console.log(fearNotLetter("abce"));
console.log(fearNotLetter("stvwx"));
```

Comment: The algorithms above all return undefined

Comment: Well you have `return undefined;` at the end of your function, so what did you expect?

Comment: I was expecting it to return the str letter at the correct index (from the if statement)

Comment: That doesn't return from `fearNotLetter` though, only from the inner function passed to `forEach` (which will be ignored). Use an ordinary `for` loop instead of `forEach` for cases like this.

Comment: Makes sense, and thanks that explains it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  let letter;
  let testArr = [0, str.charCodeAt(0)];
  str.split('').forEach((item, index)=>{
      testArr[0] = testArr[1];
      testArr[1] = item.charCodeAt(0);
      if(testArr[1] != (testArr[0] + 1)){
        letter = index ? str[index]: undefined;
      }
    })

  return letter;
}

console.log(fearNotLetter("abce"));
console.log(fearNotLetter("stvwx"));
console.log(fearNotLetter("abcdefg"));
```

Comment: This is inefficient because you iterate through the entire string, even if you find the missing letter straight away. It's better to use a `for` loop instead of `forEach` - then you can `break` out of it, or even `return` from the whole function, when you've found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the above (Ritesh and Robin), I also created my own solution (Ritesh solution is better).

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {

  let testArr = [0, str.charCodeAt(0)];
  let letter;

  str.split('').forEach((item, index)=>{
      testArr[0] = testArr[1];
      testArr[1] = item.charCodeAt(0);
      if(testArr[1] != (testArr[0] + 1)){
        letter = str[index];
      }
    })

let finalLetter = letter.charCodeAt(0);
finalLetter--;
let codeToLetter = String.fromCharCode(finalLetter);
let regex = /[a-zA-Z]/

if(regex.test(codeToLetter)){
  return codeToLetter;
} else {
  return undefined;
}
}

console.log(fearNotLetter("abce"));
console.log(fearNotLetter("stvwx"));
console.log(fearNotLetter("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```